# ASP.NET MVC EF 6: define a lookup table/model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, lookup

i am trying to define a database model in code-first to see and display which user is assigned as a specialist for the record data.
I have a very simple model for the user:

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Next I have defined two (simple) models which define the data that can be edited by the user and the specialist should be assigned to using a dropdownlist:

```
public class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string orderNumber { get; set; }
    public int specialistID { get; set; }
    public virtual User specialist{ get; set; }
}

public class Part
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string partNumber { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int specialistID { get; set; }
    public virtual User specialist{ get; set; }
}
```

What kind of relation between the models can be used without having a navigation property for each table in the User model?

Do I need to use additional tables to define the relationship: User.Id-Order.specialistID and the relationship: User.Id-Part.specialistID ?

Is there a smarter way out-of-the-box by Entity Framework?

Many thanks for your answers.
Pascal

Comment: Navigation properties are optional. With your model and default EF conventions you've already defined 2 `one-to-many` relationships. Such relationships do not require separate table (they are represented with FK column in the `many` side tables). Are you experiencing concrete issues with your model? If yes, please edit your question to include them.

Comment: May you clear if the edited data and the specialist is many-to-one or one-to-one?

Comment: Hello, it is a one - to - many relation. A specialist can be assigned to many Parts. The second relation is that a specialist can be responsible for several orders. Question was, if it is necessary to create additional tables to define the relation. Ivon Stoev answer helped me a lot to get my solution running.

Comment: Thank you Ivan. Your answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

By default when you add forign-key constraint to the many-to-one table the Entity Framework add **virtual property** to the entity class and **virtual ICollection** to the **User**.